# Wordpress: Display different navbar & widgets based on users landing page

Tags: wordpress, plugins

With Wordpress looking to display different navbar, footer & widgets, based on a users landing page.

So is there a way to set a cookie, or take the landing page url and set as a variable throughout the visitors experience. They would NOT be logged in users.

For example they go from a landing page about /new-york to a blog page, and then navigation retains the new-york navbar on the blog pages.

Similarly inside a marketing banner area, there'd be a different widget depending on the landing page. E.g. the detroit landing page vistor sees a car widget, and the new york landing page visitor sees a (stereotypical ) pizza widget.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/zen-menu-logic/) plugin will do the trick. But I have to say that I'm not 100% sure about it, but my reputation is too low to place a comment.